# FindFirstFile/FindNextFile и русские символы

Tags: c++, winapi

Писал простой рекурсивный поиск файлов по маске. С английскими символами всё работает прекрасно, но как только программа встречает русский, то передаёт в буфер мусор и функция вылетает. Пытался взять код с этого сайта (с похожего вопроса), но он также не работает с русскими символами.
Пример кода:

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> StdString;
```

функция для поиска файлов в текущей папке

```
void ScanFolder(const StdString & folder, const StdString & mask)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA find_data;
    HANDLE find_handle = FindFirstFile((folder + mask).c_str(), &find_data);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == find_handle)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            cout << folder << find_data.cFileName << endl;
        } while (FindNextFile(find_handle, &find_data));
        FindClose(find_handle);
    }
```

и рекурсивная функция для поиска папок и вызова первой функции

```
void FindFileRecursive(StdString start_path, const StdString & mask)
{

    start_path = rtrim(start_path) + _T("\\");

    ScanFolder(start_path, mask);

    WIN32_FIND_DATA folder_data;
    HANDLE folder_find = FindFirstFileEx
        (
            (start_path + _T("*")).c_str()
            , FindExInfoStandard
            , &folder_data
            , FindExSearchLimitToDirectories // поиск папок
            , NULL
            , FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH
            );

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == folder_find)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            if (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY & folder_data.dwFileAttributes)
            {
                if (strcmp(folder_data.cFileName, ".") && strcmp(folder_data.cFileName, ".."))
                {
                    FindFileRecursive(  start_path + folder_data.cFileName, mask)
                }

            }           

        } while (FindNextFile(folder_find, &folder_data));
        FindClose(folder_find);
    }
}
```

Ошибка из за того, что в функцию передаются отрицательные значения (русские буквы). Как правильно передать строку в качестве аргумента в данном случае?

Comment: В настройках проекта какие параметры _UNICODE/_MBCS заданы? Вместо `strcmp` попробуйте использовать `_tcscmp`. И вообще, не следует смешивать C и C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подозреваю что у вас отключен UNICODE. Ядро Windows работает с юникодом. WinAPI для char-ов конвертирует входные wchar-ы в char-ы, вызывает функции ядра, получает результат в wchar-ах и снова конвертирует их в char-ы. Таким образом ваша функция будет интенсивно заниматься онанизмом: выделять/освобождать память для промежуточных результатов и гонять туда-сюда char-ы в wchar-ы.

Но вам видимо этого мало, и решили для увеличения объема онанизма привлечь ещё и стринги. Которые тоже при каждом чихе занимаются выделением/освобождением памяти, и возможно тоже всякими конвертациями char-ов/wchar-ов. Непонимание русских символов заложено именно в них. Просто WinAPI работает без проблем.

Возьмите один буфер достаточного объема, и напишите одну функцию. Всё будет работать.

```
void ScanFolder(LPTSTR pFolder, LPCTSTR pMask)
{
  size_t nLen = _tcslen(pFolder);
  pFolder[nLen++] = '\\';

  WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
  HANDLE hf;

// Файлы по маске
  _tcscpy(pFolder + nLen, pMask);
  hf = FindFirstFile(pFolder, &fd);
  if ( hf != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
  {
    do
    {
      if ( !(fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) )
      {
// TODO:
      }
    } while( FindNextFile(hf, &fd) );
    FindClose(hf);
  }

// Дочерние папки
  _tcscpy(pFolder + nLen, _T("*.*"));
  hf = FindFirstFile(pFolder, &fd);
  if ( hf != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
  {
    do
    {
      if ( fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY )
      {
        if ( _tcscmp(fd.cFileName, _T(".")) && _tcscmp(fd.cFileName, _T("..")) )
        {
          if ( fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT )
          {
// TODO: Это ссылка, решаешь сам лезь туда или нет
          }
          else
          {
            _tcscpy(pFolder + nLen, fd.cFileName);
            ScanFolder(pFolder, pMask);
          }
        }
      }
    } while( FindNextFile(hf, &fd) );
    FindClose(hf);
  }

  pFolder[--nLen] = 0;
}
```

Для ANSI версии буфер (максимальная длина пути) составляет MAX_PATH. Для UNICODE 32767 символов. Но чтобы использовать "длинный путь" он должен начинаться с четырех символьного префикса `"\\\\?\\"`. Например `L"\\\\?\\C:\\и так далее"`.