# remove() не удаляет файлы с кирилицей

Tags: c++, файловая-система

Пытаюсь удалить файлы из папки, но к сожалению функция remove не работает с русским языком.

// пример использования функции: remove для удаления файла file.txt

```
#include <iostream>                             // для оператора cout
#include <cstdio>                               // для функции remove

int main ()
{
  WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
  HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(LPCTSTR("D:\\Folder\\*.txt"), &FindFileData);
  FindClose(hFind);
  std::string myfile =  "D:\\Folder\\" + FindFileData.cFileName;  //  для примера возвращает файл "file - копия.txt"; 
  if( remove(myfile.c_str() ) != 0 )    //  file.txt
      std::cout << "Ошибка удаления файла"; // при удалении file - копия.txt всегда здесь
  else  
      std::cout << "Файл успешно удалён"; // при удалении file.txt все нормально
  return 0;
}
```

Возможно, проблема с кодировкой представления русских символов и как то русский нужно преобразовать в ANSI перед отправлением в функцию remove()

Edit

Переписал через wstring, но тоже не заработало, если в названии найденого файла есть русские символы. Если же используются только английский и/или цыфры, то также файл удаляется.

```
int main ()
{
  WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
  HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(LPCTSTR("D:\\Folder\\*.txt"), &FindFileData);
  FindClose(hFind);
  std::string findFile = FindFileData.cFileName;
  std::wstring wfindFile (findFile .begin(), findFile .end()); 
  std::wstring myfile =  L"D:\\Folder\\" + wfindFile ;  //  для примера возвращает файл "file - копия.txt"; 
  if( _wremove(myfile.c_str() ) != 0 )    //  file.txt
      std::cout << "Ошибка удаления файла"; // при удалении file - копия.txt всегда здесь
  else  
      std::cout << "Файл успешно удалён"; // при удалении file.txt все нормально
  return 0;
}
```

Попробовал еще один вариант, но также безрезультатно.

```
std::string utf8String = FindFileData.cFileName;

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> convert;
std::wstring utf16String = convert.from_bytes(utf8String);
std::wstring myfile = L"d:\\Folder\\" + utf16String;
_wremove(myfile.c_str());
```

Comment: Дело тут не в `remove`, а в кодировке текста, я думаю. Вы под какой ОС работаете и с каким компилятором?

Comment: Windows Embedded XP, Visual Studio 2013 В консоле вместо русского отобр ажаются вопросы

Comment: В таком случае, мне кажется, правильнее воспользоваться WinAPI функцией [`DeleteFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa363915(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Проверил обе функции возвращают GetLastError 123

Comment: Правильно понимаю, что не работает именно с кирилицей и файл не держит никакой сторонний процесс? Попробуйте распечатать текст ошибки. Возможно, станет понятнее причина. 
    cout << "Ошибка удаления файла '" << fname << "': " << strerror(errno) << '\n';

Comment: 123 - это "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." - то есть, нужно правильно передать имя.

Comment: Да проблема только если в названии русские символы

Comment: Хороший ответ уже тут был вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/521204/findfirstfile-findnextfile-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B

Answer (score 1):

Проблема возникает при конвертации не ASCII символов в C-style строку (myfile.c_str()). Просто замените

```
std::string myfile =  "D:\\Folder\\" + FindFileData.cFileName;
```

на

```
std::wstring myfile =  L"D:\\Folder\\" + FindFileData.cFileName;
```

Подробнее [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/112997/)

Comment: Ответ ссылка - не ответ! Дайте ответ человеку, процитируйте статью с хабра, но не просто ссылку. Что если хабр загнется.

Comment: Не могу с вами согласиться, так как в данном случае - именно ответ.  Статья компактна и полностью покрывает вопрос и отвечает на него

Comment: Но строку добавили с примером... Алочность...

Comment: std::wstring myfile =  L"D:\\Folder\\" + FindFileData.cFileName;  не преобразуется из-за различия типов , remove(myfile.c_str()) также не работает

Comment: @askeet: А если скомпилировать программу как Unicode-приложение?